# If $\mathbb P(A)=0.61, \mathbb P(B)=0.56$ and $\mathbb P(A\cup B)=0.81$. Find $\mathbb P(A \mid A\cap B)$

Tags: conditional-probability

I’ve figured out what $(A\cap B)$ is, which is $0.36.$

I tried putting 0.61 over 0.36 but the answer is over 1 which is obviously incorrect. How do I answer this question?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ and $B$ both occur, then certainly $A$ occurs, so the probability is $1$.  If you want to use the formula,

$$\Pr(A|A\cap B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap(A\cap B))}{\Pr(A\cap B)}=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A\cap B)}=1$$

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense, but I don’t understand the working out. Are you able to explain it?

Comment: Do you know the formula for conditional probability?  It's  $$\Pr(X|Y)=\frac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)}$$  I'm just applying it with $A=X, Y=A\cap B$.

Comment: But do you see the first A in Pr(∩(∩))? Why does it disappear? Apologies for asking too much. You’ve been very helpful

Comment: When you have a question like this, I suggest you draw a Venn diagram.  That will be more convincing than the formal proof, which is $$A\cap(A\cap B)=(A\cap A) \cap B = A\cap B$$

Answer (score 1):

Obverse that $A \cap B \subseteq A\implies P(A|A\cap B) = 1$. Or maybe you want to find $P(A|A \cup B)$ ?

Comment: I’m trying to find Pr(A|A⋂B)

Comment: Thanks a rl lot

Comment: @haidangel: Sure, any time...

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are in $A\cap B$ you are in $A$ with probability 1

Comment: What can be more straightforward than this? :-)